# "Quote: List buttons not appropriate for this object" exception while migrating one org to another org

Tags: migration

I am moving my one org to another salesforce org using eclipse-Force.com IDE but facing this issue "Quote: List buttons not appropriate for this object" and unable to find any solution. And i have also checked that their is not list button on Quote in Source Org. Any suggestion would be helpful, thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Dies the target Org have Quotes enabled?

Comment: @Alex Yes Quote enabled

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the searchlayout.searchFilterFields section from your xml file and then deploy

```
<searchLayouts>
  ...
  <searchFilterFields>Problematic_part__c<searchFilterFields>
  ...
</searchLayouts>
```

This seems to be related to the search Filter Fields

Comment: Thanks Ravikant for your response but <searchLayouts> XML are same for Quote object in both org Source and Destination.

Comment: This resolved my issue when I had the same error. Thanks so much!